# How to install TDM-GCC in powershell and open Mingw command prompt?

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, gcc, tdm-gcc

I'm now running https://github.com/StefanScherer/windows-docker-machine window docker container and opened powershell prompt to install GCC, Golang and a bunch of other stuff. How can I install TDM-GCC https://github.com/jmeubank/tdm-gcc/releases/download/v10.3.0-tdm64-2/tdm64-gcc-10.3.0-2.exe within powershell and then open the Mingw prompt? 'cz I have no GUI and the container would lose its state after exit.

Tried download it to my mac machine and `Start-Process` in powershell but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try the standalone build from https://winlibs.com/ - no installation needed, just extract the archive and start using GCC.